# propagate vertex attributes using igraph package in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am looking for a smart way to propagate vertex attributes in a directed graph using the igraph package with the R language. I am not that familiar with the nomenclature on networks and the properties but I 'll try my best.

An example:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
from_to_df = data.frame(from = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
                    to = c("c", "c", "d", "e", "g", "g")
                    )
attributes_i_have = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1)
attributes_i_want_to_have = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
color = c('red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'green')

network_i_have = graph_from_data_frame(from_to_df, directed=T) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("label", value = attributes_i_have) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = color) 

plot(network_i_have)
```

As the names say, that is the graph have and I want to do kind of backward propagation of the vertex attributes to get a graph like that:

```
network_i_want_to_have = graph_from_data_frame(from_to_df, directed=T)%>%
  set_vertex_attr("label", value = attributes_i_want_to_have) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = color) 

plot(network_i_want_to_have)
```

Any help is appreciated.